# IE7 Div Bug overflow:auto

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I need some help , I have an IE7 CSS issue (some clients still use IE7 so I need to code for it).

I am having trouble with some nested divs and a horizontal scroll bar which works fine in IE8+ and everything else.

What happens is, the overflow should create a horizontal scroll bar, so the content inside can expand beyond the edge of the screen.

HTML

```
<div class="CenterBoxFlow Rounded" >
 <div class="CenterBoxContainer" id="panetest">
  .. Content
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.CenterBoxFlow { border: 1px #ccc solid; width: 1110px; white-space: normal; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; overflow: visible; padding: 15px; margin-bottom: 6px; text-align: center; float: left; position:relative; }
.CenterBoxContainer { text-align: left; width:1110px; overflow:auto; white-space:nowrap; vertical-align:top; overflow-y:hidden; display:inline-block; position:relative;  }
```

FYI, the content is also a series of divs with the following style:

```
.Chart_Small { padding: 5px; width: 152px; white-space: normal; display: inline-block; position: relative; *display: inline; zoom: 1; }
```

Any suggestions on getting the div to overflow properly in IE7 would be great.

Peter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE7 CSS Scrolling Div Bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67665/ie7-css-scrolling-div-bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand why, but removing `white-space: normal;` from .Chart_Small fixes this bug for me. Can you check if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
*zoom:1;
```

It solves many ie7 bugs.. ;)